# Java 8: how to get the first number greater than 10 in a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As per subject: How can I get the first number greater than 10 in a stream?

Is there any method of `stream()` that may help in this case?

I would like that as soon as the stream reaches the first element above 10 it will return it without looping the rest. (kind of "break" the loop)
Is it possible?

Comment: filter by `x->x>10`, then get the first one?

Comment: @bayou.io I know that, however my question is what's the function that get the first one without parsing the whole stream.

Comment: And what if there is NO such value in the stream?

Comment: @fge Optional.empty gets returned, just tried

Comment: I believe @fge is asking what you *wanted* it to do if such a case were to happen. (But of course simply returning an optional would be the idiomatic Java 8 way, now that it's available, since it lets the caller decide.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`findFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--):

```
// new Random().ints() // or whatever the stream is
    .filter(i -> i > 10).findFirst();
```

`findFirst` returns some type of [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), so you need to decide what to do with it if you don't find a match.

This is similar to a loop like this:

```
for (int i : ...)
    if (i > 10)     // "filter"
        return i;   // "findFirst" (may or may not be present)
```

Comment: An `Optional` (or an `IntOptional` in this case) has `.isPresent()` so you can use this method